# How to consume a soap web-service in c# and pass XML in request?

Tags: c#, soap

I need your help to find the best way to call a soap web-service in c# ?

I know using the web-service reference feature in c# is a good one.

I tried using it and it did not work ?

Here is the xml that I want to post

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://temenos.com/CUSTDETS">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <cus:EDBCUSTDETS>
             <WebRequestCommon>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <company></company>
                <password></password>
                <userName></userName>
             </WebRequestCommon>
             <EDBCUSTDETSType>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <enquiryInputCollection>
                   <columnName></columnName>
                   <criteriaValue></criteriaValue>
                   <operand>EQ</operand>
                </enquiryInputCollection>
             </EDBCUSTDETSType>
          </cus:EDBCUSTDETS>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

After adding the reference for the WSDL in the service references folder, I named it as ServiceReference1.

Now I Can see in my code :

How to achieve this request ?

how can I add company, password and user Name and the enquiryInputCollection parameters ?

Is there any best practice for achieving this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have successfully generated proxy classed from WSDL, then you should be good to go. I assume you should have been provided web service documentation for consuming them.

Look for `service client classes` to begin with.

eg:

```
var client = new ServiceReference1Client();
client. ? //(should list Methods and you can find Types of Paramaters to build them.)
```

If you check in web.config/app.config, and if you see  and `<client>` and `<endpoint />`, this is where you supply endpoint address. If you need to send client certificate you might want to start with either  or  and setting security eg:

```
 <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
 </security>
```

There are lot of resources on WCF capabilities to achieve this. Hope this helps mate.